# Batch cutting result string from command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to properly cut result from command in batch? I wrote something like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`whoami`) DO (
    @ECHO %%F%:~7,4%
)
ENDLOCAL
```

In my case "whoami" returns "`europe\archont"`. After running this batch I receive `"europe\archont:~7,4"` instead of `"arch"`
Where I did mistake?

Comment: You can only do a sub-string on an environmental variable.  You cannot do it on a FOR variable.  Assign the FOR variable to an environmental variable first and then do the substring outside of the FOR command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no further functions to perform within your `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('WhoAmI') Do Set "IAm=%%~nxA"
Echo(%IAm:~,4%
Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`whoami`) DO (
    set "str=%%F"
    @ECHO !str:~7,4!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Code only answers can be made much better with some descriptive text regarding how it is different and/or what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of relying on fixed string length, just use the `\` as delimiter:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%F in ('whoami') do set "im=%%F"
```

when needed, you can cut that:

```
echo %im:~,4%
```

Comment: I don't see any need to stipulate the number of tokens or provide the delimiter… _see my answer_